# Raspberry pi 4b won't boot. Red led lights up but green led dead

Tags: pi-4, boot

So I've been using my pi4b for a couple of days and I was trying to run some open cv python programs on it when it suddenly go disconnected(I use the pi via putty and VNC viewer). Ever since that the pi would not boot. The red led lights up every time I power it, but the green led doesn't work at all. Once in every 10 times or so the green led will light up once for less than a second and then go dead. The CPU doesn't heat up either.

Here are the fixes I've tried.

I bought a new SD card and flashed the OS on it and tried to boot the pi. Didn't work.

I followed this guide [this guide](https://www.fastoe.com/blog/rpi-4_400-eeprom-recovery-guide) to try eeprom recovery but it didn't work.

I tried pressing down on the sd card slot to ensure that there's no loose connection but that didn't work either.

What should I do? I am a beginner all kinds of assistance will help.

Comment: `green led doesn't work at all` contradicts `led will light up once for less than a second`

Comment: power supply should be the first thing to check

Comment: @jsotola I am powering the pi from my laptop's usb port.

Comment: the green light will light up for less than a second very very rarely, as if by chance.

Comment: `powering the pi from my laptop's usb port` is it capable of supplying 15Watts?